# how to save in database after successful login?

Tags: php, mysql

i just want to add the ip address and the username after successful login this is my code. The problem is it did not continue to the profile after login but when i remove the insert query it continue to the profile what should i do ?

```
 session_start();
    if(isSet($_POST['username']) && isSet($_POST['password']))
    {
    // username and password sent from Form
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
    $password=md5($password);

    $result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT PatientId   FROM patient WHERE PatientId='$username' AND Password='$password'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1)
    {
    $_SESSION['PatientId']=$row['PatientId'];
    echo $row['FirstName']. ' '.$row['LastName'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    $query=mysqli_query($db,"insert into login_history_patient(PatientId,IP)Values('".$username.",'".$ip"')");

    }

    }
```

Comment: Forget to close `$username` quotes and `concate on ` $ip `  it would be`('".$username."','".$ip."')");`

Comment: I just saw that now ^ which I initially said to check for errors and would have spotted the syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - Funny what a dot will do to someone's day.

Comment: its ok now bro thankyou ididnt notice i just go to the submiting page thankyouuu

Comment: plus, storing plain text instead of a hash; not a good idea.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash and verify passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: what I meant by plain text storage, is that MD5 is just as bad as plain text. You need to use a more recent hashing method, as outlined in my answer and in @JayBlanchard 's comment/links.

Answer (score 2):

The first initial problem here, is that you're not checking for errors and assuming success right off the bat.

This line:

```
$query=mysqli_query($db,"insert into login_history_patient(PatientId,IP) 
Values ('".$username.",'".$ip"')");
```

being modified to:

```
$query=mysqli_query($db,"insert into login_history_patient (PatientId,IP) 
Values ('".$username.",'".$ip"')") 

or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

would have signaled the syntax error.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- Missing a concatenate `'".$ip"'` => `'".$ip."'`

You could have also used:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if (!$result)
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_error($db));
}

else{ echo "Success."; }
```

Ideally, using `mysqli_affected_rows()` will give you a better result, if the query truly was successful.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Plus, you're storing passwords using MD5 which is a very bad idea because it's old and considered broken, should this site go or is LIVE.

You should also use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

- *Your users will thank you for it.*

Answer (score 1):

Always use properly formatted queries like this:

`SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = '" . $id . "';`

The last query you are executing, is half properly formed (you're missing a dot):

`$query=mysqli_query($db,"insert into login_history_patient(PatientId,IP)Values('".$username.",'".$ip."')");`

The `.` was missing after the `'".$ip"'`

Answer (score 0):

In any language syntax of Concatenation of string with variable is important.
If you are putting variables into query make sure that the quotes start and properly, .(dot) is used to concatenate so end the string , use .(dot) put variable again use .(dot) , start the string.

```
"string".$variable."string continues.."
```

hope it helps..